# how to link the ios-ngn-stack in the project of idoubs to my own project

Tags: ios

The ios-ngn-stack can product some .a libraries that provide some class I can use in my own sip Client.

I know if I want to use these class, I need to make a cross reference project.

However, when I do as the way adviced on some Blogs, it just does not work. I do not know why.

I pulled-in the `iso-ngn-stack.xcodeproj` file into my project, I have set the building settings as `idoubs`, for example, search header path, search library path...

I do not know what I can do now. Does anyone have done this stuff?

Comment: Hey i think this question was asked so long , so have you figured out a solution for the same scenario .. I am looking to do the same stuff.. Please help. !!